# code to expand excel column width in php while exporting

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I am new to PHP and trying to export some DB data to Excel file as below. But in the output I want the column widths to be adjusted automatically to view the entire content. See the code I am using to export data. I am not using any third party libraries for export.

```
<?php    
require_once("db.php");   

$contents="email,time_in,v_id,time_out\n";   

$user_query = mysql_query('SELECT  * FROM table');   

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query))
{
$contents.=$row['email'].",";
$contents.=$row['time_in'].",";

$contents.=$row['v_id'].",";
$contents.=$row['time_out']."\n";
}

// remove html and php tags etc.
$contents = strip_tags($contents); 

//header to make force download the file

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report".date('d-m-Y').".xls");
print $contents;


?>
```

Is there any way to format the output ?

Comment: you are outputting a CSV-file and give it the wrong extension "XLS". With CSV, there is no way to do what you ask. Excel can do this, and you would need to find a way to create an excel-file...

Comment: as mentioned I am new to PHP. So can some one can help in exporting data to Excel from PHP